# How to hide an element if radio button is checked?

Tags: css, w3-css

Say I have Radio Buttons and a Div.

```
<input id="one" type="radio" value="1">
<label>One</label> 
<input id="two" type="radio" value="2">
<label>Two</label> 

<div id="mainDiv">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

How do I hide the div block only if radiobutton one is checked?
Without using any other language and only css.

I tried to use `+` and `~`. I dont know if im using it wrong but it didnt work.

Comment: "*I [don't] know if [I'm] using it wrong but it [didn't] work*" - so, show us how you were using it, and then we can try and help you understand why it "didn't work," and what adjustment would be necessary.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `checked` property of the `one` radio button together with the `~` combinator:

```
#one:checked ~ #mainDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #one:checked ~ #mainDiv {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="one" type="radio" name="myRadioGroup" value="1">
  <label for="one">One</label>
  <input id="two" type="radio" name="myRadioGroup" value="2">
  <label for="two">Two</label>

  <div id="mainDiv">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, you can check the example from documentation MDN [Toggling elements with a hidden checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked#toggling_elements_with_a_hidden_checkbox)